# What is the Fritzing part for the connector block on the Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino, fritzing

The Arduino UNO has a number of connector blocks, e.g. the A0-A5 block. I want to design a PCB using Fritzing that has the same type of connector block. What is the part name for this type of connector, and is there a part with the ability to have a variable number of connectors, like what can be done with the Fritzing generic IC part?

Comment: Wouldn't https://forum.fritzing.org/ be the place to ask this?

Comment: I will try there too, but forum.fritzing.org is not a stack exchange site. In general I prefer stack exchange sites.

Comment: OK, but please don't post the Fritzing wiring diagrams here. If you have a question we'll need a schematic diagram which can be generated by Fritzing with some tidy up by you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Generic female header` part, which is the first part in the connectors section of the `Core parts` library.

After you have placed it on the canvas, you can change the number of pins in the inspector.